# Can I do a EF statement Where( c => c.NameStr == (is element in list<string> ) )?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do a Where statement but check to see if a field member matches an item in a list of strings instead of just a string.  My entities are autogenerated from the DB and stored in the .edmx file.

```
//selectedAgencys is a List<string> 

List<v_MapCrimeData> list = ent.v_MapCrimeData
                               .Where(c => c.AgencyName == (element in list selectedAgencys));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
List<v_MapCrimeData> list = (from c in ent.v_MapCrimeData 
                            from x in selectedAgencys 
                            where x == c.AgencyName 
                            select c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 11):

You want to see if the list contains the field, so you can use the [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)

`nt.v_MapCrimeData.Where(c => selectedAgencys.Contains(c.AgencyName))`

Since you indicated you're using Linq to Entities you might want to try a join.

```
List<v_MapCrimeData> list = v_MapCrimeData.Join(
            selectedAgencies, 
            c => c.AgencyName,  //key selector for v_MapCrimeData
            a => a,             //key selected for selectedAgencies
            (c, a) => c).ToList(); //result selector (i.e. return the v_MapCrimeData)
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.       Tried this:   List<v_MapCrimeData> list = ent.v_MapCrimeData.Where(c => selectedAgencys.Contains(c.AgencyName)).ToList();

Comment: Oh. Linq to Entities is something else then. What type is selectedAgencys? Maybe a join is what you need.

Comment: can always do nt.v_MapCrimeData.ToList().Where(c => selectedAgencys.Contains(c.AgencyName)) to avoid the cannot be translated into a store express (though this could cause other issues)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ignore case,

```
nt.v_MapCrimeData.Where(c => selectedAgencys.Any(a => a.Equals (c.AgencyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.    Tried this:  List<v_MapCrimeData> list1 = ent.v_MapCrimeData.Where(c => selectedAgencys.Any(a => a.Equals(c.AgencyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

.Where(i => listocheckagainst.Contains(i.valuetoBeChecked))

Edit: spent time signing up to SO and someone else answered